# who and when creates jacoco.exec files?

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

Maven call:
    mvn -e org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.4.201502262128:prepare-agent 
        install -Dmaven.test.error.ignore=true -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true

the build takes a while. I assume having "jacoco.exec" files is crucial for reporting code coverage, so I wanted to see if any "jacoco.exec" files were created - without waiting for the whole build&analysis to complete.

so far I don't see any "jacoco.exec" files.

I am wondering when exactly these files are supposed to be created: after the complete Maven build or after each module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that these jacoco.exec files are created by Jacoco Maven plugin after each Maven sub-module build. no need to wait for the full build to complete.